# Configure the interface on the Visco TenGigabitEthernet 3750E switch

Tags: switch

I can help configure the interface on the cisco TenGigabitEthernet 3750E switch, the switch module recognizes me X2-10GB-SR, but not that brings interface configuration.

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/10GE_Tx_Matrix.html#_Toc455743811) about compatibility matrix of Cisco 10G tranceivers, it's clear that X2-10GB-SR is compatible with the 3750E switch.